# Laravel best practice when non-linear queries are needed

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Sometimes I need to run a non-linear query, that aggregates or merges data.

e.g.

```
SELECT a.field, b.field2
FROM a
JOIN (
  SUB QUERY....
) AS b
ON a.a = b.b
ORDER BY ...
```

But I'm always in doubt about the best way to implement it. I have some choices but I don't really like any of them:

- **DB::select($query)**: simple but problematic if the query has some controls on where or order by clauses
- **Using query builder DB::table()->join()->limit()**: useful for controls but maybe too verbose
- **Using \Models\A::select()->join()->limit()->get()**: I don't really like because returned object are not A model.
- **Using a special model that, thanks to global scope, has a "mandatory" left condition**: fully featured buy maybe over-engineered

How do you approach those situations? What do you think is the best practice?

Comment: Then use the raw query function

Comment: @RaymondNijland do you intend the plain query builder using DB facade?